# Auto add user firstname in author field in django with custom User model

Tags: python, django

I created Custom User model in django using below code

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(_("Username"), max_length=50, unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', ]

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

And I also created another model for user profiles like below.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name=_("User"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(_("First name"), max_length=50)
    middle_name = models.CharField(_("Middle name"), max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_("Last name"), max_length=50)
    dob = models.DateField(_("D.O.B"), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=False, null=False)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(_("Profile picture"), upload_to='user/profile/', blank=True)
    webiste_link = models.URLField(_("Websites"), max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
```

At last I created another model for Category like below.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name=_(
        "Author"), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_category')
    title = models.CharField(_("Title"), max_length=50)
```

I want to auto save logged in user full name  instead of user email address.  By the way i used below code to auto save logged in user. It works but It only save user email address. But I want user full name instead of email or username.

```
    obj.author = request.user
    super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Comment: where you want to save the users full name? in which field?

Comment: There is no field as full_name or something in your model in which full name must be store. Do specify the existing field name or add another field to store the full name

Answer (score 1):

You could define a method in the `UserProfile` model to build this fullname, as you may need it in another function :

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name=_("User"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    [...]

    def get_fullname(self):
        return ' '.join([name for name in [
                      self.first_name, 
                      self.middle_name, 
                      self.last_name
                      ] if name])
```

So you keep this way to save the user foreignkey in a `Category`:

```
obj.author = request.user
```

And later, to call the fullname on a category instance you can use :

```
# cat = Category.objects.first() 
cat.author.userprofile.get_fullname()
```

Comment: Thanks for your helps its working but I've one questions can i use objects.all() instead of objects.first(), if not then how can i get list of categories with respective to their author name

Comment: of course you can, that was only a way to set the context on the example instance `cat`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a filed called **full_name** in **UserProfile** model

```
Class UserProfile(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name=_("User"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     first_name = models.CharField(_("First name"), max_length=50)
     full_name = mdoels.CharField(_("Full name"),max_length=100)
     middle_name = models.CharField(_("Middle name"), max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
     last_name = models.CharField(_("Last name"), max_length=50)
     dob = models.DateField(_("D.O.B"), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=False, null=False)
     profile_image = models.ImageField(_("Profile picture"), upload_to='user/profile/', blank=True)
     webiste_link = models.URLField(_("Websites"), max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

     def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
          if not self.full_name:
              self.full_name = self.first_name + " " + self.middle_name + " " + self.last_name
          super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And then using author you can call the users full_name